# Spring. @Transactional - исключение NoSuchBeanDefinitionException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Изучаю Spring, и сейчас я на этапе транзакций. Стали интересны именно транзакции Hibernate. Но при запуске программы возникает исключение:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.vladhuk.examples.HibernateSpitterDao' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:343)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1101)
    at com.vladhuk.examples.Main.main(Main.java:12)
```

Конфигурация:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class Config {

    @Bean
    public BasicDataSource dataSource() {
        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();

        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/java_test?useSSL=false & serverTimezone=Europe/Kiev");
        dataSource.setUsername("vladhuk");
        dataSource.setPassword("1");

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();

        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan("com.vladhuk.examples");

        return sessionFactory;
    }

    private Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create");
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");

        return hibernateProperties;
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        HibernateTransactionManager tm = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        tm.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory().getObject());
        return tm;
    }
}
```

Класс DAO, вызывающий исключение:

```
@Component
@Transactional
public class HibernateSpitterDao implements SpitterDao {

    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Autowired
    public HibernateSpitterDao(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    public void addSpitter(Spitter spitter) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.save(spitter);
        session.close();
    }

    public Spitter getSpitterById(long id) {     
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(Spitter.class, id);
    }

    public void saveSpitter(Spitter spitter) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.update(spitter);
        session.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Какой бин не создается? И при чем здесь транзакции?

Comment: У вас ваш Бин не указан в вашем HibernateSpitterDao, и что находится на 12 строке в Main?

Comment: Спринг контейнер не знает о бине "HibernateSpitterDao", хотя он указан, как "component". Скорее всего вам нужно добавить бин в "component scan" или заимпортить его через аннотацию "@Import".

Comment: @Dred обращение к компоненту через getBean()

Comment: Вообщем попробовал объявить компонент компонент явно через @Bean, после чего ошибка пропала.

Comment: О чем мы выше и писали :)